# Copy phone's photo to app's directory

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an iPhone app that uses the user's photos to create a new special photo. I want to store the special photo within my app, but give the user the ability to change it by using the original photo.

What happens when the user deletes the original photo from their photo albums on the phone?

Should I save a copy of the original photo into my app, just in case? Or is there a better way?

My question is similiar to [iOS save photo in an app specific album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972185/ios-save-photo-in-an-app-specific-album), but I want to know if this is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

You can save a copy of photo/image in your application's document directory and access it from there when you want to use.
so if a person deletes it from original location, you will have a copy.

Comment: Yes because the photo albums on the phone is different than your application's document directory. So no problemo!