# Phonegap (cordova) save image to custom album

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I do not know much about `Objective-C`.
I need to save the image in the gallery to custom name album and i used `Canvas2ImagePlugin` but image save to album camera roll.

`Canvas2ImagePlugin` using:

```
UIImage* image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] autorelease];    
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

How to use the name album in the function `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`? Or use another function?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't  know about `phonegap`. but i can give you hint that how we can achieved in `ios`. with help of `ALAssetsLibrary`, we can stored photo to custom album.

```
 [self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Touch Code Magazine" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
   }];
```

Comment: The question decided. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972185/ios-save-photo-in-an-app-specific-album