# React Native - iOS save photo in an app specific album

Tags: ios, react-native, sideloading

I'm creating an iOS app. I want to save a photo to the device.

I want to save the photo to an album specific to my app, so I need to create the album, and then save photos to the album.

I've seen someone else asking how to do it in Swift here {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972185/ios-save-photo-in-an-app-specific-album/76412669?noredirect=1#comment134740802_76412669}, but I'd like to know if this can be done in React Native as well

Thanks

I haven't made any tries as of now, I'd like to know if it can be done first